# Can a fabric task execute other tasks and respect decorators such as runs_once?

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way for `execute` in fabric to respect a decorator (other than `host`, `hosts`, `role`, `roles` and `exclude_hosts` --- see [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute)), or another way to accomplish something like that)? Here is a use case:

```
from fabric.api import task, execute, run, runs_once

@task
def setup_environment():
    # ... set up env.hosts, env.roledefs, env.use_ssh_config, etc.

@task
def provision():
    # ... do some stuff on each host here, e.g. install mongodb

@task
def is_primary():
    return run('mongo --quiet --eval "db.isMaster().ismaster"') == 'true'

@task
@runs_once
def change_to_primary():
    env.hosts = []
    for host, result in execute(is_primary, roles=('mongo',)).iteritems():
        if result:
            env.hosts.append(host)

@task
def add_user():
    # ... do something here that needs to be done on primary
```

This is fine if I run the following sequence of tasks from the command line:

```
> fab setup_environment provision change_to_primary add_user
```

But since I always run `change_to_primary` and `add_user` as part of provisioning, I would like to modify `provision` so that I can run `fab setup_environment provision` and have `set_primary` and `add_user` be executed, something like this:

```
@task
def provision():
    # ... do some stuff on each host here, e.g. install mongodb
    execute(change_to_primary)
    execute(add_user)
```

However, this executes `change_to_primary` many times (does not run once), unlike the command line usage. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to execute the task on all nodes with the `mongo` role using the `roles` decorator, and begin the task by checking if the node is actually a primary:

```
@task
def provision():
    execute(stuff_to_do_on_all_hosts)
    execute(stuff_to_do_on_mongo_primaries)

@task
def stuff_to_do_on_all_hosts():
    do_stuff()

@task
@roles('mongo')
def stuff_to_do_on_mongo_primaries():
    if not is_primary():
        return
    add_user()
    do_other_stuff()
```

Another way would be to first build the list of primaries, then use the `hosts` parameter to `execute`:

```
@task
def provision():
    # ... do some stuff on each host here, e.g. install mongodb
    execute(stuff_to_do_on_all_hosts)

    # build list of mongo primaries
    primaries = [host for host, result in execute(is_primary, roles=('mongo',)).iteritems() if result]

    # run task only on those hosts
    execute(stuff_to_do_on_mongo_primaries, hosts=primaries)

@task
def stuff_to_do_on_all_hosts():
    do_stuff()

@task
def stuff_to_do_on_mongo_primaries():
    add_user()
    do_other_stuff()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, sorry I didn't see it until now!